# Flipboard transformer for Viewpager.

Tags: android, android-viewpager, flipboard

How can I implement a transformer like the one in the Flipboard app in the Viewpager using this method `transformPage()`?

Comment: It doesn't all I've found is custom views, nobody implemented it using the transformPage() method